# Read and Write to a Text File (JavaScript/HTML/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I am currently trying to learn to program in JavaScript and HTML. I am making a program that will print a number on all clients. The div that shows the number is updated every half second. I am trying to make it so all clients show the exact same number, since you cannot do that client side, I am trying to do it server side.

For example;

Ever half second it reads the text file, and every half second the number in the text file is added. If the text file is at 5, it shows five and then in a half second 6 on all clients, no matter when they loaded the page.

Here is my code:

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Money</TITLE>
 
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image:
        url('/indexbackground.jpg');
}
</style>
    
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var moneybalance = "/moneybalance.txt";
 var krbal = new File(moneybalance);
  krbal.open("w");
  //krbal.writeln("Example");
 var moneybalance = moneybalance;
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    moneybalance++;
                    $('#show').text(
                            'Money Balance '
                                    + moneybalance);
                }, 500);
            });
</script>
 
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="show" align=""></div>
 
 
        <p>
            Testing
        </p>
    </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

As you see I'm very confused, I've tried multiple things but nothing worked.

Comment: Are you trying to edit a file on the server from the client, because that's not going to work.

Comment: Nope. Not possible... Instead use ajax, and a CRUD API endpoint. (Words! Jargon! Tech!)

Comment: So the file API is used only on the clients computer generally for uploading. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File you would have to have a server setup to serve the number file and use Ajax to poll the file.